What make and model of aircraft is this?



Saw this sitting derelict on the ramp at KIDA recently.  The configuration, landing gear, a tail, etc. looks very much like a Beechcraft King Air C90, but the windows aren’t typical of that kind of aircraft.  It also does not match up with the appearance of a Beech C89 Queen Air or a C99 commuter, either.

N200MH is a 1969 Fairchild Merlin IIB, aka Swearingen Merlin.
More registration data is here, including the 2030 expiration of its certification, so it might not be all that derelict.  Flightaware reports a flight in 2021.

Thanks. I in fact did an N-number check just after posting that and found that.  I had never heard of the type before.  And the aircraft really does not look much like what you usually think of a Merlin/Metroliner.

It's at least moderately derelict: the tires are flat.

No tie-downs.  Because it's too heavy to need them??
